# Is it possible to link a detail summary in such a way that it opens the detail when clicking the link?

Tags: markdown

I'm new to writing documentation in Markdown and working on end user documentation. I want to include some written-out steps for processes in details that are closed by default. I've anchored the summaries of these details and link to them from inside the same doc. Is there a way to format the link so that it shows you the content of the detail when you click it?

Putting the anchor on the first word of the detail didn't work.